# Again: ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=500000] (LuaLaTeX, MikTeX)

Tags: luatex, tex-core, memory, reledpar, capacity

I'm getting the following error message compiling my PhD-file (used: LuaLaTeX, MikTeX 2.9):

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=500000].
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.90    \include{M02Part02}
                       
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.



Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 44238 strings out of 479059
 125007,2373549 words of node,token memory allocated 3836 words of node memory still in use:
   14 hlist, 3 vlist, 4 rule, 31 disc, 2 local_par, 3 dir, 56 glue, 5 kern, 5 pe
nalty, 4 margin_kern, 277 glyph, 139 attribute, 97 glue_spec, 22 attribute_list,
 1 temp, 7 if_stack, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:7,2:3461,3:167,4:63,5:660,6:73,7:11166,8:2,9:753,10:32,11:1490
,12:1
 62526 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+200000
 83 fonts using 27566143 bytes
 94i,19n,112p,10600b,499999s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,500000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

It's quite impossible (and maybe not even necessary) to give you a MWE, because I'm compiling a dozen of files by the `include` command. The error occurs since I'm using the `reledpar`package to create a translation (latin on the left, german on the right) including some `index` commands and footnotes. I wonder why TeX is 'already' overloaded, because I just wanted to have two or three pages as an output for testing. But, as I read in some other posts, the size of the document as a whole does not cause an error normally. Often, the solution is only: "Use LuaLaTeX!", what I'm already doing!

So... Neither this [Problems by enlarging tex memory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29015/problems-by-enlarging-tex-memory) nor this [Compiler error "save size exceeded"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161286/compiler-error-save-size-exceeded?rq=1) nor even this [TeX capacity exceeded despite system call LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231747/tex-capacity-exceeded-despite-system-call-lualatex) did work for me. Increasing the memory or the save size didn't have any consequences. I already have the shell-escape included in TeXstudio, and until the recent usage of the `reledpar` package, I didn't have any problems with it.

Please help!

**Update**
I reduced my files step by step. There was no error with the `reledpar` package in my opinion, because everything worked fine until I included my (large) bibliography created with `biblatex`. I suppose that this could overload TeX because I added quite a lot of adaptions of the style. Maybe that there is to find this coding error mentioned in the commentaries.

**Update 2**
I managed to compile my files in a normal way by putting only the .tex-files in a new folder, open it an compile it.

**Update 3 - MWE**
I created a MWE in order to see if you get the same errors. Yesterday it worked quite properly. But since today morning, the problem is something with the line numbers, I suppose: Everytime, the compiling is working once, producing a PDF in which the lineation isn't correct, but index and bibliography are created correctly (in the log: Please rerun LaTeX). During the second run, I get the "save-size" warning. I hope the MWE works. I didn't reproduce the structure of my document which I'm creating with front-, main- and backmatter, but I included all the options which I consider important for the problem (and its solution, maybe??). I excluded `biblatex` which is definitely not causing the error, for better overview.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, twoside=true, usegeometry, fontsize=12pt, parskip=false, 
captions=signature, 
headings=small, headings=optiontoheadandtoc, chapterprefix=true, appendixprefix=true,
numbers=noendperiod, BCOR=0.5mm, DIV=calc, headinclude=true, footinclude=true, pagesize=auto, 
headsepline=0.25pt, footsepline=false, footbotline=0.25pt, plainfootbotline=true, titlepage=true, 
toc=listof, toc=index, toc=bibliography, toc=graduated, listof=chapterentry, nonumberline, 
chapterentrydots=true, sectionentrydos=true, cleardoublepage=empty, open=right]{scrbook}

% Schrift
\usepackage{microtype} % Verbesserung des Satzspiegels und des Satzes
\usepackage{unicode-math} % lädt auch fontspec mit (Voß Wiss. Arb. S. 30)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % direkt ä, ö etc. von der Tastatur eingeben

\usepackage{lipsum}
% Sprache
\usepackage[french, italian, english, ngerman]{babel} % ngerman als Hauptsprache
\usepackage[autostyle=true, french=guillemets, english=american, german=quotes]{csquotes}

%Index
\usepackage[splitindex,xindy]{imakeidx}
% reledpar/reledmac

\usepackage[nocritical, noeledsec, noend, noledgroup, series={A}]{reledmac}
\usepackage[advancedshiftedpstarts, nomaxlines]{reledpar}
\renewcommand*{\ledlsnotefontsetup}{\raggedleft\tiny}% left
\renewcommand*{\ledrsnotefontsetup}{\raggedright\tiny}% right
\newcommand{\memorybreak}{\pausenumbering\resumenumbering}

\begin{document}
\chapter{some chapter}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}\beginnumbering\numberpstarttrue
\pstart[\section{Steph. Doletus Gulielmo Scaevae, s.}]
\ledouternote{Gryph. 3} Vberrimum ad te scribendi argumentum dum undiquaque colligo, \& diutius, quam sperabas, sileo, tuam forte de meo in te amore atque singulari beneuolentia opinionem mirum in modum fallo, neque tardi aut parum diligentis nomen non subeo: sed si qua istiusmodi suspicionem tibi mea tam longa taciturnitate\index{some index} commoui, diligentiam adhibebo, illam ut quam primum\footnoteA{some footnote} deleam.
\pend\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}\beginnumbering
\numberlinefalse % keine Nummerierung in der Übersetzung
\pstart
some translation
\pend\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: "save size exceeded" almost always mean there is a coding error somewhere. Try to make a small example which uses more than a few hundred from the "s" values (499999s). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134599/2388

Comment: My bet is that one (or maybe two (or maybe just `M02Part02`)) is causing the problem.  Try including only a few, and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: @Teepeemm You're right that this file causes the error. If I don't include it, I don't get the error. This is clear, because only in this file, the environment ```pages``` of the ```reledpar``` package is used.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry for this question, but where can I find these values? If I find them, I will create a MWE.

Comment: look at the end of your log. It shows the statistic: `94i,19n,112p,10600b,499999s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,500000s`, so you can also see when it goes up.

Comment: Ok I'll try to create a MWE (probably until tomorrow) which shows the error for you.

Comment: which size has you .bbl file ?

Comment: @Maïeul Surprisingly, it's zero because I wasn't able to finish the compiling.